# submit specific nested form onkeydown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submitting a nested form without refresh. Each row contains a textfiled called `inputbox`, and when a user should hit the `w` key on a particular row of the nested form it should be submitted to the database without refresh

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputbox').keydown(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '87') {
            $('.team_short_pass').submit(); // Submit form code
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".loader").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
            data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../scripts/inesert_new.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.msg').html(data);
                    $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
                    $('.msg').slideDown(100).delay(3000).slideUp(100);

                }
            });

        }

    });
});
```

with my script when i submit it does send nothing to the database

Comment: The problem is `$(this).serialize();` since `$(this)` doesn't refer to your form. Please use your form's selector explicitly here.

Comment: Why are you submitting the form??? If you do not want the page to refresh than why do you have `$('.team_short_pass').submit();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to use $('.team_short_pass') instead of $(this) to access form data as $(this) points to input box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inputbox').keydown(function(event){
     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
     if(keycode == '87'){
       $(this).parents('.team_short_pass:eq(0)').submit(); // Submit form code
       event.preventDefault();
       $(".loader").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
       data = $(this).parents('.team_short_pass:eq(0)').serialize();

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../scripts/inesert_new.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
             $('.msg').html(data);
             $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
             $('.msg').slideDown(100).delay(3000).slideUp(100);
           }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: it only inserts the first record even if hit the w key in the four row and also does refresh the whole page